# Wix Velo — How to work with Array of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm currently building a website on Wix, and have come across a problem I can't think myself out of. Neither Wix support or the Wix Velo Forum have been able to help me out.

I have a repeater that is connected to the Stores/Products collection, and in the Stores/Products collection there's a collection field that contains additional info sections on the product. I have three info section; Tempo, Genre and Tags. Each contains a description.

**It looks like this:**

```
    [
  {
    "title": "Tempo",
    "description": "<p>142 BPM</p>\n"
  },
  {
    "title": "Genre",
    "description": "<p>Jazz</p>\n"
  },
  {
    "title": "Tags",
    "description": "<p>Frank Ocean, Travis Scott</p>\n"
  }
]
```

**I have figured out how to pull the individual objects with this code:**

```
export function audioRepeater_itemReady($item, itemData, index) {
    let product = $item('#dataset3').getCurrentItem(itemData._id)
    let ArrayAdditionalInfo = []
        ArrayAdditionalInfo = product.additionalInfoSections
        ArrayAdditionalInfo.forEach((element) => {
    
            console.log(element.title)
            console.log(element.description)
        })
```

But I want it to be able to figure out if eg. the Title === "Genre", then it will show the description from that array, like this:

```
{
        // if equal to this:
        "title": "Genre",

        // show me this
        "description": "<p>Jazz</p>\n"
      },
```

The whole plan with this is to show the description output in a text element that I can implement in the repeater.
I have tried with *if* statements, but I just can't put it together myself. If this is confusing I'll gladly elaborate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure if I understood the question correctly, but if you want to show all titles, and, conditionally the description if the title is `Genre`, you could just use a Ternary:

```js
let data = [{
    "title": "Tempo",
    "description": "142 BPM\n"
},{
    "title": "Genre",
    "description": "Jazz\n"
},{
    "title": "Tags",
    "description": "Frank Ocean, Travis Scott\n"
}];

data.forEach(e => $("#products").append(
    `<p>Title: ${e.title}${
        e.title === "Genre" 
            ? "<br>description: " + e.description 
            : ""
    }</p>`
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="products">
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but Wix just doesn't seem as versatile when it comes to accessing data through your own data collections. I'll probably try and come up with a workaround based on your code. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue related to handler. You use repeaters onItemReady handler, which is not the best option for your case. It calls for each row in repeater. Instead of this I recommend to use dataset's onReady

```
$w("#dataset3").onReady( () => {
     console.log("The dataset is ready");
     $w("#audioRepeater").getItems(0, 20).then( (result) => {
        let items = result.items;
        items.forEach((element) => {
           if (element.title === 'Genre') {
              doWhatDoYouWant(element)
           }
        }) 
     } ).catch( (err) => {
        let errMsg = err.message;
        let errCode = err.code;
     } );
} );
```

Please take into consideration that this block should be inserted into $w.onReady